# How to change effective_io_concurrency in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I'm trying to change these two parameters (random_page_cost and effective_io_concurrency) in my Postgresql 12 database. For the first one I found this command :

```
alter database mydb set random_page_cost=1.1;
```

However, for the second I couldn't find how to do it. I thought about changing the postgres.conf file but it's not there at all. Can I add it ? or is there a similar command to random_page_cost ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLESPACE mytablespace SET effective_io_concurrency = 1;
```

Replace mytablespace with your specific tablespace and choose another number for effective_io_concurrency.

Corresponding documentation for V10:

- [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-resource.html#:~:text=effective_io_concurrency](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-resource.html#:%7E:text=effective_io_concurrency)
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-altertablespace.html